# Cant choose multiple values in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services

I made a logical Mistake in Report builder in below there is 2 Sequel Query that is connected to @Income Parameter, However in the report I get this result, which doesn't make sense because it just shows same income.

[image]

I think its because I can't choose multiple incomes. When I try to choose multiple values I get this error.

[image]

This query can be executed but does not work efficiently. I am also experiencing the same for Age Queries, I cant choose multiple age as you can see in the error picture.

```
(SELECT MIN(YearlyIncome) FROM vTargetCustomer WHERE (@Age = Age) AND (@Income = YearlyIncome) AND (@Buyer = BikeBuyer)) as MinIncome,
(SELECT MAX(YearlyIncome) FROM vTargetCustomer WHERE (@Age = Age) AND (@Income = YearlyIncome) AND (@Buyer = BikeBuyer)) as MaxIncome
```

This is my Stored Procedure (DataSet1)

```
CREATE PROC GET_TargetCustomer (
@Age INT,
@Income int,
@Buyer int



) as

BEGIN
SELECT DISTINCT


   (SELECT AVG(Age) FROM vTargetCustomer WHERE (@Age = Age) AND (@Income = YearlyIncome) AND (@Buyer = BikeBuyer)) AS AVGAge,
(SELECT SUM(BikeBuyer) FROM vTargetCustomer WHERE (@Age = Age) AND (@Income = YearlyIncome) AND (@Buyer = BikeBuyer)) as TotalBuyers,
(SELECT MAX(Age)  FROM vTargetCustomer WHERE (@Age = Age) AND (@Income = YearlyIncome) AND (@Buyer = BikeBuyer)) AS OldestCustomer,
(SELECT AVG(YearlyIncome) FROM vTargetCustomer WHERE(@Age = Age) AND (@Income = YearlyIncome) AND (@Buyer = BikeBuyer)) as AVGIncome,
(SELECT MIN(Age)  FROM vTargetCustomer WHERE (@Age = Age) AND (@Income = YearlyIncome) AND (@Buyer = BikeBuyer)) AS YoungestCustomer,
(SELECT MIN(YearlyIncome) FROM vTargetCustomer WHERE (@Age = Age) AND (@Income = YearlyIncome) AND (@Buyer = BikeBuyer)) as MinIncome,
(SELECT MAX(YearlyIncome) FROM vTargetCustomer WHERE (@Age = Age) AND (@Income = YearlyIncome) AND (@Buyer = BikeBuyer)) as MaxIncome


END

GO
```

I have Created Data Set For each Parameter

AgeDataSet for Age Parameter

```
SELECT DISTINCT Age FROM vTargetCustomer ORDER BY Age ASC
```

IncomeDS For Income Parameter

```
SELECT DISTINCT YearlyIncome FROM vTargetCustomer ORDER BY YearlyIncome ASC
```

BuyerDS for Buyer Parameter

```
SELECT DISTINCT BikeBuyer FROM vTargetCustomer ORDER BY BikeBuyer ASC
```

Can Someone help me to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple values in your paramter, the query would need to be able to use them using IN instead of equals (=).

And is there a reason why you're not combining them all in a single SELECT?

```
SELECT AVG(Age) AVGAge, SUM(BikeBuyer) TotalBuyers, MAX(Age), MIN(Age)
FROM vTargetCustomer 
WHERE (Age = @Age) 
    AND (Income IN (@YearlyIncome)) 
    AND (BikeBuyer = @Buyer)
```

Comment: @HamzaB Hannover's answer is correct but you will have to use this directly in your dataset query, not inside a stored proc.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I need to use in my stored proc. But without erasing my above code in the proc, if  I use Hannovers answer to my dataset, What do you think?

Comment: If you really have to use a stored proc then you cannot use `IN` directly. You will have to parse the parameters in your stored proc. Why can you not use the query directly in the dataset query?